# thread_local static class is destroyed at invalid address on program exit

Tags: c++, c++14, thread-local, static-initialization, destruction

I have an issue with the destruction of a thread_local static object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct UsesLoc {
    UsesLoc() {
        loc.counter++;
    }

    struct Loc {
        Loc() {
            std::cout << "I am at   " << this << " and counter is " << counter << std::endl;
        }
        ~Loc() {
            std::cout << "I was at  " << this << " and counter is " << counter << std::endl;
        }

        int counter = 0;
    };

    static thread_local Loc loc;
};

thread_local UsesLoc::Loc UsesLoc::loc;

int main()
{
    {
        UsesLoc usesloc;
        std::cout << "loc is at " << &UsesLoc::loc << " and counter is " << UsesLoc::loc.counter << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, compiling and running on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8bcfdaffa6a6da7 reveals that the thread_local object is always at the same location and the counter values are (0,1,1):

```
I am at   0x7f9dc817673c and counter is 0
loc is at 0x7f9dc817673c and counter is 1
I was at  0x7f9dc817673c and counter is 1
```

Conversely, when I locally compile with MinGW and run, I get, for instance,

```
I am at   0x507874 and counter is 0
loc is at 0x507874 and counter is 1
I was at  0x7efdd000 and counter is 2686552
```

Clearly, an uninitialized object at a different memory location is destroyed.

Did I oversee anything non-deterministic? How can I ensure that the correct object is destroyed?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you considered using Meyers singletons instead of class-scope static objects? I don't know what the thread-safety/initialization/destruction guarantees are for the latter...

Comment: You sure it needs to be `thread_local static` and not just `thread_local`?  It might be the combination that of the two keywords that screws it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof If I understand correctly, this would mean moving the class-scope static to a function-scope static. I tried it but nothing changed. I also tried moving it to the global scope, but it's the same again. It seems as if, for some reason, the object is destroyed only at a point where the address is not known any more.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes, a `thread_local` non-static member is not permitted IIRC. And in the global scope - which I also tried - `thread_local` and `thread_local static` are supposed to be the same.

Comment: Sorry, the part about the global scope is incorrect.

Comment: I think it's a bug in MinGW. Which version is it? I tried your code with one version of all compilers @ godbolt that could produce runtime output and none reproduced this.

Comment: That would be interesting (yet disappointing). I'm using MinGW 7.3.0. 32-bit as shipped with Qt 5.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a [hint from Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58339548/thread-local-static-class-is-destroyed-at-invalid-address-on-program-exit#comment103037577_58339548) that this might be a compiler bug, I did a bit of research and it seems to be indeed an issue already reported before:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83562
- https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/727/

That being said, the code is correct and the pointer to the object being destructed points to the same object that was constructed before when using a standard-compliant compiler.